# Flushing MemoryCache ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, .net-core, memorycache

I am trying to flush my cache after I update an item, and I have tried a few different options and none are working as expected

```
public class PostApiController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPostService _postService;
    private readonly IPostTagService _postTagService;
    private IMemoryCache _cache;
    private MemoryCacheEntryOptions cacheEntryOptions;
    public PostApiController(IPostService postService, IPostTagService postTagService, IMemoryCache cache)
    {
       _postService = postService;
       _postTagService = postTagService;
       _cache = cache;

      cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
          .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }

    [HttpGet("{url}", Name = "GetPost")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string url, bool includeExcerpt)
     {
       Post cacheEntry;
       if (!_cache.TryGetValue($"GetById{url}{includeExcerpt}", out cacheEntry))
       {
         cacheEntry = _postService.GetByUrl(url, includeExcerpt);
        _cache.Set($"GetById{url}{includeExcerpt}", cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
      }

      if (cacheEntry == null)
      {
        return NotFound();
      }

      return new ObjectResult(cacheEntry);
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBody] Post item)
    {
      if (item == null)
      {
         return BadRequest();
       }

      var todo = _postService.GetById(id);
      if (todo == null)
      {
         return NotFound();
      }

       _postService.Update(item);
       _postTagService.Sync(item.Tags.Select(a => new PostTag { PostId = item.Id, TagId = a.Id }).ToList());
       //Want to flush entire cache here
       return new NoContentResult();
     }
```

I have tried to Dispose() MemoryCache here but on next Api call, it is still disposed. Since the keys are somewhat dynamic, I can't just get the keys. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why call it GetById and not GetByUrl?

Comment: Anyway, can you reconstruct the GetById{url} part in the Update method?

Comment: Surely the `todo` item has a `Url` property you can use to re-insert this item back into the cache? Or even remove both `includeExcerpt` true and false variants?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the dictionary instead. This way you can use the dynamic keys for entries and one single static key for the dictionary container, which can be stored in the cache instead of storing each entry separately.

Something like that:

```
private const string CachedEntriesKey = "SOME-STATIC-KEY";

[HttpGet("{url}", Name = "GetPost")]
public IActionResult GetById(string url, bool includeExcerpt)
{
    Dictionary<string, Post> cacheEntries;
    if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CachedEntriesKey, out cacheEntries))
    {
        cacheEntries = new Dictionary<string, Post>();
        _cache.Set(CachedEntriesKey, cacheEntries);
    }

    var entryKey = $"GetById{url}{includeExcerpt}";
    if (!cacheEntries.ContainsKey(entryKey))
    {
        return NotFound(); // by the way, why you do that instead of adding to the cache?
    }

    return new ObjectResult(cacheEntries[entryKey]);
}
```

Comment: Issue is that key is not static. Key is variable based in params

Comment: @IsaacLevin the way I proposed allows to use dynamic keys for entries and one single static key for the dictionary container, which can be stored cache instead of entries one by one. Did you get the idea?

Comment: I did now that you phrased it like that :) I will take a look

Comment: I have rephrased the idea in the answer. Please keep us posted if that did the trick.

Comment: And what would the flush look like? Or I just reinitialize in my update?

Comment: Just get the dictionary from cache and remove the item from it (or clear all items). What kind of "flush" to you need?

Comment: I have other actions that cache as well, I would like to clear the cache similar to me restarting the web server

Comment: So what? If you remove all items from the dictionary - all cached entries will be removed. :) Do you understand how it works, Isaac?

Comment: Oh god I get it now. You aren't caching the objects your caching a dictionary of objects.

Comment: return true; // right, you got it :) Does it solve the issue? Feel free to mark as answer if it does.